# informal gesprochen vs. informell gesprochen

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, adverb, mathematics

Let's consider the following passages:

> Informal gesprochen nennen wir A und B unabhängig, wenn die Kenntnis des Eintretens von B die Prognose für A nicht ändert. Formal (für P(B) > 0):
>
> A, B unabhängig ⇔ P(A|B) = P(A)

(cf. http://mathe.weissi.net/pdf/sto_0708_v1.pdf)

and

> Informell gesprochen ist eine Verknüpfung auf einer Menge M eine Vorschrift, die je zwei Elementen x und y aus M (unter Beachtung der Reihenfolge) ein weiteres Element z von M zuordnet. Die präzise Definition ist wie folgt. ...

(cf. [http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~shoeppne/Algebra%20%28SS2010%29/Skript/alg1-3.pdf](http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/%7Eshoeppne/Algebra%20%28SS2010%29/Skript/alg1-3.pdf)).

Given that the mathematicians are not necessarily strong in German even when German is their mother language, is "informal gesprochen" or "informell gesprochen" correct in the above contexts? Clearly, in both passages the authors mean "informally speaking" and provide a plain-language definition followed by formulas, but which phrase is correct in the above contexts:

- *informal gesprochen* or
- *informell gesprochen* ?

Duden is of no help here: "informally speaking" is in both cases both "[nicht auf vorgegebenen Regeln, Richtlinien beruhend, sondern spontan [sich ergebend]](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/informal)" (since the plain-language description doesn't contain rules or formulas)  and "[dem Zweck der [ersten] Information dienend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/informell_informierend)" (since the plain-language description introduces a term (a piece of information) for the first time).

References to established sources supporting your answer are welcome.

Comment: It's *informell*. *Informal* isn't a German word. (Duden has it, but I know exactly no-one who uses it.)

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht einmal, was ein » formaler Garten « sein sollte. Das sind einfach leere Unsinnsworte.

Comment: Was ein formaler Garten ist kann man [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaler_Garten) nachlesen. Dementsprechend kann man auch ableiten, was im Text unter einem informalen Garten verstanden wird. Die Begründung warum informal kein deutsches Wort sein soll ist ... naja ^^. Auf die Art könnte ich auch behaupten endoplasmatisch wäre kein deutsches Wort ;) .

Comment: @MdAyq6 There is another Duden-entry for _informell_. Take a look at [this](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/informell_unfoermlich_formlos).

Comment: @mtwde: Tatsächlich? Das gezeigte sind Barockgärten. Ein japanischer Garten ist der Natur nachempfunden und dabei super-formell. Alles hat einen Hintergrund. *Endoplasmatisch* ist ein Lehnwort und es gibt keinen Bedarf für ein weiteres Lehnwort *endoplasmatic*. Genauso verhält es sich mit "informal" und *informell*.

Comment: Beobachtung aus der Hüfte: In manchen (nicht allen) Wörtern, die beide Endungen -al/-ell haben, erscheint mir der Gegensatz in der Bedeutung ähnlich oder vergleichbar dem der Endungen -ig/-lich.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context (and only in it), I am very much in favor of **informal**. The reason is that "informell" has a strong social connotation, f. ex.

> Vor dem EU-Gipfel gab es ein kurzes informelles Treffen.

whereas here we are bound to a purely scientific context.

This seems also be backed by the Duden as the meanings given for "informell" do not fit well here:

> ohne [formalen] Auftrag -> does not fit at all
>
> ohne Formalitäten, nicht offiziell -> does not fit well

On the other hand, the meaning for "informal"

> nicht auf vorgegebenen Regeln, Richtlinien beruhend, sondern spontan [sich ergebend]

fits quite well. The author does not keep to the standard rulings for expression here, but uses plain language, as you already mentioned correctly.

Having all said this I still do not want to be understood in the sense that "informell" is incorrect, but it does not fit as well as "informal".